# getUserMedia permission denied after clicking the "allow" button

Tags: javascript, html, webcam, ubuntu-12.04, getusermedia

I'm trying to use the `navigator.getUserMedia()` and as expected on my webpage (or for example https://apprtc.appspot.com/) I'm asked to allow or deny access to my webcam/microphone.

But after I click "allow" nothing happens and on my log I can see:

```
NavigatorUserMediaError {code: 1, PERMISSION_DENIED: 1}
```

I'm on Ubuntu 12.04 and tried on Chromium 24.0.1312.56, Chrome 24 and beta 25 and Firefox 18.0.2. Same problem everywhere.

I can access my webcam on webpages using Flash like here http://www.xarg.org/project/jquery-webcam-plugin/

Any idea what is the problem?

Comment: Can you show us the code? Or is it your setup that does not work with pages that have no problems on other computers?

Comment: I guess the problem is coming from the fact that I'm under Ubuntu.
But I was wondering if there is something to do with for example chrome flags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the webcam and it's working.
So apparently Microsoft Lifecam VX-7000 doesn't work on Ubuntu 12.04 with `navigator.getUserMedia` because this cam works on Windows 7 (at least with Chrome).